# No such directory or file

Tags: command-line, permissions

I would like to use the chmod command in terminal. It requires to have path/to/file. I type:  `nicholas@Bigmachine:~$ chmod a+rwx /home/WDRecovered` (which is an existing directory) but I get the message    cannot access '/home/WDRecovered': No such file or directory

I am probably doing something wrong, I am new here.
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank

Comment: if you type `cd/home` then `ls` what directories are listed? Please [edit] you question, not add to to comment trail.

Comment: mind that linux is also case sensitive.